# What are these reflector looking things?

Tags: headlight, lights, lexus

I've recently got a new vehicle, and I noticed these plastic parts in the headlight cluster but not sure what they do, they look reflective but when I turned the headlights and indicators on but can't see any particular light.

This vehicle is equipped with adaptive headlights (I can have them on full beam and if a vehicle is infront it will dim the side flowing onto their direction to avoid blinding).

Any ideas? Not seen anything in the manual.

Edit: These seem to appear of a few new vehicles, but still clueless as to what they are. Next stop, email Lexus directly.

[image: Lexus IS300h Jeadlight cluster]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You might look to see if these are the Daytime Running Lights (DRL). You'd have to have someone take a look for you though. Most DRL's only come on when the vehicle is in gear.

Comment: Hi @Paulster2 thank you! - The DRLs are underneath this light cluster (they're the swooping part in the bottom right and left)

Comment: They look like the typical tiny reflector lenses for LEDs. Did you test the adaptive feature? Try watching the headlights while you have someone crank the steering wheel all the way from side to side. I have two vehicles with similar lights (not Lexuses) that illuminate when going around sharp corners.

Comment: @dwizum will have a go at this as soon as it's dark!